# How to upload real time video to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-camera

I am trying to upload a real-time video stream from the video camera to the AWS S3 bucket. Here assuming that camera settings like target IP or domain are fully controllable. But I don't know how to implement this on AWS services. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can your video camera send a stream to somewhere? What format would it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AWS you can achieve this by using [Amazon Kinesis Video Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/video-streams/features/).

You can use the Gstreamer Docker image to stream video from the camera to Kinesis Video Streams. Have a look at the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/examples-gstreamer-plugin.html#examples-gstreamer-plugin-docker)